# Regex to exclude certain characters

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use JQuery Validate to use a regex pattern to detect when 3 characters I, O or Q (case insensitive) are in a 17 character string alphanumeric string and then present an error. I've been able to detect these characters when the string contains them completely e.g qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq, however single or more occurrence e.g bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbqq don't seem to be detected.

The code I'm attempting to use is below, I thought the regex would be reasonable straight forward -

```
regex: "[^ioq]/i"
```

however that doesn't seem to work completely, the full javascript i'm using is below

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.addMethod(
            "regex",
            function(value, element, regexp) {
                var re = new RegExp(regexp);
                return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
            },
            "Please check your input."
    );
    $("#navbar").validate({
      onfocusout: true,
      onkeyup: false,    
      rules: {
        VIN: {
          required: true,              
          minlength: 17,
          maxlength: 17,
          regex: "[^ioq]/i" 
        }
      },
      messages: {
        VIN: {
          required: "Please provide a VIN",
          regex: "A VIN excludes letters I, O and Q",
          minlength: "Enter a 17 character VIN",
          maxlength: "Enter a 17 character VIN",
        }
      },
```

Fiddle example at - http://jsfiddle.net/f07mz4x0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use negative lookahead here to detect single presence of blocked characters like this:

```
/^(?![^ioq]*[ioq])[a-z0-9]{17}$/i
```

Here `(?![^ioq]*[ioq])` is negative lookahead that prevent matching `[a-z]{17}` when input has even a single occurrence of letters `i, o or q` (case insensitive).

Comment: It should be /^(?![^ioq]*[ioq])[a-z0-9]{17}$/i to properly capture alphanumeric strings